# Событие тега <audio> volumechange и muted

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

У меня есть самый обычный **audio** тег, перед загрузкой контента аяксом, мне нужно проверить состояние тега **audio**, а именно заглушен (muted=true) он или нет.

Я нашел событие **volumechange**,

```
$("#test")[0].addEventListener("volumechange", function() {
    alert("work!");
}, true);
```

но оно просто возвращает true, когда включается или выключается звук, а мне нужно сделать проверку именно на заглушку звука (muted=true):

```
$("#test")[0].muted=true;
```

Буду благодарен, если кто-то подскажет, есть ли подобное событие у audio, ибо я такого не нашел. Или как можно осуществить на (muted=true) проверку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение оказалось очень простым, если кому-то будет полезным:

```
if (audio.muted) {
    код...
}
```